# How do I use max() in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that looks like this:

```
col1   col2  col3  
------ ----- ----- 
A      1     trout
A      2     trout
B      1     bass
C      1     carp
C      2     tuna
D      1     salmon
```

I really only want to select the rows with the max value for col2.

The query I want to generate would return the following:

```
col1   col2  col3  
------ ----- ----- 
A      2     trout
B      1     bass
C      2     tuna
D      1     salmon
```

I've tried something like this:

```
select col1, max (col2) as mCol2, col3
from mytable
group by col1, col2
```

In this case I get:

```
col1   Mcol2 col3  
------ ----- ----- 
A      2     trout
B      1     bass
C      1     carp
C      2     tuna
D      1     salmon
```

As you can see, I still get `C, 1, carp`, when I'm only wanting `C, 2, tuna`.

I've considered trying to do something like

```
select col1, col2, col3
from mytable
where 
    col1-n-col2 in (
        select col1, max (col2) as mCol2
        from mytable)
group by col1, col2
```

But I don't think that's legal in SQL. What obvious solution have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were close

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3
from mytable t,
    (select col1, 
        max (col2) as mx 
    from mytable
    group by col1) m
where m.col1 = t.col1
and m.mx = t.col2
```

Answer (score 7):

If (col1, col2) is unique, or if you don't mind duplicates in the case of ties:

```
SELECT T1.col1, T1.col2, T1.col3
FROM mytable T1
JOIN (
    SELECT col1, MAX (col2) AS mCol2
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY col1
) T2
ON T1.col1 = T2.col1
AND T1.col2 = T2.mCol2
```

If you want to choose any row in the case of a tie (requires ROW_NUMBER support, i.e. not MySQL):

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM (
     SELECT
         col1, col2, col3,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2 DESC) AS rn
     FROM mytable
) T1
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Analytic functions are by far the best way to solve this sort of problem as they will perform much better than a sub query over a large data set.

Either try the second query provided by Mark Byers or try the query shown below:

```
select 
  col1, 
  max (col2) as mCol2, 
  max (col3) keep (dense_rank last order by col2) as col3
from mytable
group by col1
```

This uses the [`LAST` analytic function](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions071.htm#i1000905) to get the last value in each group after ordering by col2. The `MAX` used for col3 is required by the syntax but is only really a tie-breaker.

Comment: +1 for being the best answer here. Although you are not using analytic functions here at all, only aggregate functions ...

Comment: @RobvanWijk I realised I was using an aggregate function just before submitting the answer and it seemed more trouble than it was worth to change (although I'm now writing a long comment to justify it...). For me analytics are the best way to solve most problems and I use the first and last functions fairly regularly in both the analytic and aggregate forms.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify **which** database you're using - on SQL Server and a few others, you could use a CTE (Common Table Expression) with a windowing function to get your rows:

```
;WITH HighestOnly AS
(
   SELECT
       col1, col2, col3,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2 DESC) AS 'RowNum'
   FROM 
       MyTable
) 
SELECT 
   col1, col2, col3
FROM
   HighestOnly
WHERE 
   RowNum = 1
```

This will "partition" your data by the criteria specified (`col1`) and dish out consecutive numbers for each data partition, starting at one - ordered by a second criteria given (`col2 DESC`). So for each "partition" of data, the row with the highest value in `col2` will have `RowNum = 1` - and that's what I'm selecting here.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    select mytable.col1, mytable.col2, mytable.col3
    from mytable
    join 
     ( select col1, max(col2) as col2
       from mytable 
       group by col1) as mytablemax
    on  mytable.col1 = mytablemax.col1 
    and mytable.col2 = mytablemax.col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach

```
With max_qry as
(select col1, max(col2) as mcol2 from mytable group by col1)
select m.col1, m.col2, m.col3
from mytable m join max_qry on m.col1 = mq.col1 and m.col2 = mq.mcol2
```

Answer (score 0):

hei..

I don't have an Oracle database installed but for MySQL this is wrong..

It is because of your space in syntax... the correct version is

```
SELECT MAX(column) ...
```

and not

```
SELECT MAX (column) ...
```

I don't think that with space is recognized as a function...